# How to call default constructor first before function code?

Tags: c#, syntax, constructor

I have two constructors:

```
public ViewDigiFiles()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeMyGLControl();
    InitializeMyScrollBar();
    InitializeMouseEvents();
    InitializeKeyboardControls();
    InitializeContextMenu();
    InitializeComboBox();
    InitializeToolStripView();
    InitializeListBox();
    setToDefaultScale();
}

public ViewDigiFiles(List<SelectDataLog.DataLog> d)
    :this()
{
    //how to execute this line first before calling this()?
    datalogList = d;
}
```

Is there a way to execute `datalogList = d;` before the the initialize functions without copying and pasting everything underneath it? Thanks!

Comment: Are the methods called in the constructor dependent on `datalogList` being set to a valid value?

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking this question

Comment: So then calling `new ViewDigiFiles()` would not be valid?

Comment: If so how does calling default constructor work?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `dataLogList` may be initialized to a valid value (meaning that the default constructor still makes sense)

Comment: @Michael ... perhaps, but I am asking in order to define the problem

Comment: @SriramSakthivel good question, now I think of it, I always need dataLogList to be initialized before I initialize the Listbox, thanks!

Comment: So, IMO you don't need a default constructor at all. Otherwise you need to provide a valid default value for it.

Comment: Yep, I think I'm going to do that instead and take out the default constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extract all method calls in the parameterless constructor into an `Init` method:

```
private void Init()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeMyGLControl();
    InitializeMyScrollBar();
    InitializeMouseEvents();
    InitializeKeyboardControls();
    InitializeContextMenu();
    InitializeComboBox();
    InitializeToolStripView();
    InitializeListBox();
    setToDefaultScale();
}

public ViewDigiFiles()
{
    Init();
}

public ViewDigiFiles(List<SelectDataLog.DataLog> d)
{
    datalogList = d;
    Init();
}
```

Comment: `Init()` should probably be private/protected, no?

Comment: Good solution, I guess there is no cool syntax I can use after all

Answer (score 2):

Consider switching how the constructors are calling each other. Do it the other way around:

```
public ViewDigiFiles()
    : this(CreateDefaultDataLogList())
{
}

public ViewDigiFiles(List<SelectDataLog.DataLog> d)
{
    datalogList = d;
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeMyGLControl();
    InitializeMyScrollBar();
    InitializeMouseEvents();
    InitializeKeyboardControls();
    InitializeContextMenu();
    InitializeComboBox();
    InitializeToolStripView();
    InitializeListBox();
    setToDefaultScale();
}

private static List<SelectDataLog.DataLog> CreateDefaultDataLogList()
{
    // Initialize with however many default items.
    return new List<SelectDataLog.DataLog>();
}
```

Comment: this would defeat the purpose of having a default constructor in the first place wouldn't it?

Comment: @Chris why would it defeat the purpose of a default constructor?

Comment: sorry should have been more specific, datalogList is already initialized to a new list as a private global variable.

Comment: @Chris In that case, `dataLogList` doesn't even need to be initialized (it's overwritten with the constructor's parameter).

Comment: @Chris Yes it makes any field initializer for `datalogList` superfluous. I would just remove it if going with this solution.

Comment: @mikez thanks for the solution, but my datalogList always need to be a non empty list because InitializeListBox() sets the default selected value to 1 which will cause a IndexOutOfRange execption. I will remove the default constructor completely.

Comment: @Chris If your default is complicated you could also call a method to create the default list, as I show in my edit.